# Change Customer Account Sidebar Menu Navigation Title

Tags: magento2, blocks, customer-account, menu, navigation

I want to change magento 2 customer navigation sidebar menu title.

for example: **Account information** turns into **My Profile**

What I've done so far:

**customer_account.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Customer::account/navigation.phtml">
                <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link" remove="true"/>
                <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Profile</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/edit</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </referenceBlock> 
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because it's getting **overwritten in the luma theme**.

If you want to change that, create a theme that extends the luma theme and change it there.

Check the file under `theme-luma/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml`

If you change it there it will work, but.. you don't wanna change that directly in the luma theme.. ;) so extend the theme and *voilà*!

Create a custom theme and activate it. Make sure it's a child of the `luma theme`

> **theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>My new super awesome fabulous theme!</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

then create the file in your new theme **Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml** with these contents :

> **customer_account.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string"
                         translate="true">Awesome new dashboard
               </argument>
           </arguments>
       </referenceBlock>
       <!-- Change Account information -->
       <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string"
                         translate="true">My Profile</argument>
           </arguments>
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: how to do it from custom module?

Comment: can't, theme has last word when it comes to xml. Module -> sub Module -> theme -> childtheme

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html

Answer (score 0):

**You need to create `customer_account_index.xml` at**

**For custom Module:**

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml

**For Custom Theme**

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Profile</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/edit</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now flush cache and try.

Comment: it's not working from custom module

Comment: Please check layout it must be __customer_account_index.xml__ and it must be at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout`

Comment: It all depends on the theme you're using. If you're theme does not change it it will work, but if your theme is or extends luma, won't work. See magento documentation link in the comment above.

Comment: @IdhamChoudry I tested this code with a custom module and it's working fine. Please try after flushing cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order by changing the number here in the `XML's`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order History</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">220</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

So if you want sales order history to be next to My dashboard you'd need to change `220` to `240`. Its `240` because the dashboard order number is `250`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking how to change the title of the menu add this to your local customer_account.xml inside the body tag.

```
<referenceBlock name="sidebar.main.account_nav">
   <action method="setBlockTitle">
      <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Account Menu</argument>
   </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.4.6-p4, I changed My Account sidebar menu title by using the below steps.

1. create new customer_account.xml in app/design/frontend/Packagename/themename/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml
2. Add below code in the customer_account.xml file

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="sidebar.main.account_nav">
          <arguments>
               <argument name="block_title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Account</argument>
          </arguments>
      </referenceBlock>
   </body>
   ```