# How to add a title to sidebar in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, topmenu, sidebar

I have moved my navigation menu to the sidebar by using

```
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="sidebar.main" before="catalog.leftnav"/>
```

I wonder if I can add a title to it?

Right now, it looks like this and I want to add "Categories" on top of the menu:

I wonder if I can add this.

Comment: You can find the answer at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213391/change-customer-account-sidebar-menu-navigation-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you can add title to block through XML by:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="catalog.topnav.label" before="catalog.topnav">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<div>Categories</div>]]></argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom block to display custom text in `sidebar.main` container as below

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="about_us.label">
    <arguments>
        <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">About Us</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

For more check [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/123665/84221)

Comment: it is not showing anything, do you by any chance know why?

Comment: @Magento_learner have you added this inside `sidebar.main` ?